# $V_{\omega}$ satisfying certain ZF axioms

Tags: set-theory, axioms

The question I have is trying to show that the set $V_{\omega}$ satisfies the axiom of extensionality, and foundation, where $V_{\omega}$ is the set defined below.
$$V_\omega:=\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}V_n $$
where $V_n$ itself is defined as:
\begin{equation*}
V_n:=
    \begin{cases}
            V_0= \phi \\
           V_{n+1}=V_n \cup \mathcal{P}(V_n) \\
    \end{cases}
   \end{equation*}

$\bullet$ *Extensionality*
Two sets are equal if and only if they have the same members.

$\bullet$ *Foundation*
Every set $X$ has a $\epsilon-$ minimal member, that is an $x \in X$ such that $y\in x$ for no $y \in X$.

I have the following corollary's which I can use, which I have listed below:\

$\underline{\textit{Corollary 1:}}$ 
$\bullet$ $V_{\omega}$ satisfies the last two conditions for inaccessibility

2) If $X \in V_{\omega} $ implies $\mathcal{P}(X) \in V_{\omega}$

3) $X \in V_{\omega}$ implies that the range of any function with domain X and values in $V_{\omega}$ is a member of $V_{\omega}$.

$\underline{\textit{Corollary 2:}}$
$\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\quad V_{n+1}=\mathcal{P}(V_n)$\

$\underline {\textit{Corollary 3:}}$
If $X \in V_n$ then $X \subseteq V_n$.

I managed to get the other axioms done, but I am pretty lost on these ones. I can do the forward direction for the axiom of extensionality, but cannot get the reverse direction. Foundation I think I might have to use induction for, but i'm not sure. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me what axioms you need help with exactly, and where.

Comment: whoops, sorry, posted the axioms now.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't proved that yet, show that $V_\omega$ is transitive. Namely, if $x\in V_\omega$, then $x\subseteq V_\omega$.

For Extensionality, if $x\neq y$, then there is some $z\in x$ such that $z\notin y$ (or the other way around). But since $V_\omega$ is transitive, $z\in V_\omega$. What does that tell you?

To show Foundation holds, if $x\in V_\omega$, show there is a function mapping each $y\in x$ to the least $n$ such that $y\in V_n$. Now take the least $n$ for which $x\cap V_n$ is non-empty, and take $y$ in that intersection. What can you say about $y\cap x$?

Comment: So would the following proofs work?: (sorry for multiple comments, wasn't sure how to upload)
Extensionality:
The $\implies$ direction holds because if two sets in $V_{\omega}$ are equal, then they must have the same members by definition of equality.

Conversely, for the $\impliedby$ direction, let $X \in V_{\omega}$ and $Y \in V_{\omega}$. Then, without loss of generality $X \in V_i$  and $Y \in V_i$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$. By corollary 3, $X,Y \subseteq V_i$. But, by assumption, X and Y have the \textit{same elements}, and since they are both $\subseteq V_i$ this implies that $X=Y$

Comment: Foundation Part 1:
Let $X \in V_{\omega}$, we wish to show that X has an $\epsilon$-least member. By definition, $X \in V_{n+1}$ for some n$\in \mathbb{N}$. By corollary 2, $V_{n+1}= \mathcal{P}(V_n)$, which implies that $X \subseteq V_n$. Now, if $x_j \in X$ is the minimal element of X, we are done. Otherwise, $\exists$ an $x_1 \in x_j$ since $V_{\omega}$ is inductively defined by taking the union of previous elements. Now, if $x_1$ is the least element of $X$, then we are done.

Comment: Foundation part 2:
If not, we can continue this process since if $x_1$ isn't the least element in $X$, then $\exists$ an $x_2 \in x_1 \in X$, which if it is the least element of $X$
, then again we are done, and if not, we form the chain:\\

$$... x_3 \in x_2 \in  x_1 \in x_j \in X \in V_n$$

whereby we are guaranteed to eventually terminate on the least element in X, which means that $V_{\omega}$ has a least element since $V_n \subseteq V_{\omega}$, because $V_{\omega}$ itself has a starting point, namely $\phi$. Thus, $V_{\omega}$ satisfies the axiom of foundation.